# Remove the use of 'any' in TypeScript code with two parameters bound by generic type and partials

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the following TypeScript code:

```js
type SportJournal = { type: 'S', sport: boolean, id: string}
type ArtJournal = { type: 'A', art: boolean, id: string}
type Journal = SportJournal | ArtJournal;
type JournalState<T extends Journal> = {state: string, journal: T}

const updateSportJournal = (journal: Partial<SportJournal>) => { console.log(journal)}
const updateArtJournal = (journal: Partial<ArtJournal>) => { console.log(journal)}

const updateJournalState = <T extends Journal>(journalState: JournalState<T>, journal: Partial<T>) => {
  if (journalState.journal.type === 'S') {
      updateSportJournal(journal as any);
  } else if (journalState.journal.type === 'A') {
      updateArtJournal(journal as any);
  }
}
```

I try to use the `updateJournalState` function for both `SportJournal` and `ArtJournal`.
But calling the `updateSportJournal` method without casting to any will lead to the following compiler error.

```
Argument of type 'Partial<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<SportJournal>'.   
Types of property 'type' are incompatible.     
Type 'T["type"]' is not assignable to type '"S"'.       
Type '"S" | "A"' is not assignable to type '"S"'.         
Type '"A"' is not assignable to type '"S"'.
```

Is there any way to remove the use of any in this code and make it type-safe?

Comment: Unfortunately `JournalState<SportJournal> | JournalState<ArtJournal>` is not a discriminated union type so the check you're doing would never work directly (it's more of a "nested" discriminated union, but TS doesn't support those, see [ms/TS#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758)).  You could refactor away from generics and use custom type guard functions, or make it even more generic so your implementation is of the form `journalUpdaters[journalState.journal.type](journal);`.  Which way would you like to see in an answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I would love to see a possibility with type guards. It would be perfect if it could also handle other Journal types for example HistoryJournal, MathJournal, LanguageJournal

Comment: [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxjv7w) shows the two main implementations; the former abandons generics but is clunky since you can't type guard multiple variables at once.  The latter one is how I'd probably prefer to write this myself, since the compiler is much better at generic lookups.  Let me know which of those you'd like to see written up, if any.

Comment: Thanks again for your really fast reply. I think I would also prefer the generic lookup option. Is there a way to keep the `type` in the definition of the Sport / Art Journal type. As seen in this playground link https://shortest.link/j92Y. I send an example on how I would like to use the function in the end

Comment: You can make aliases however you want like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N75Z4W); does that suffice?

Comment: Yes I guess this would suffice. Great answer. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use [control flow anlysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow the type of `journal` by checking the value of `journalState.journal.type` inside the body of `updateJournalState()`.  Unfortunately this won't work for two reasons:

- TypeScript does not narrow or re-constrain [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters like `T` due to control flow analysis.  You might narrow a value of type `T` to some more specific type, but `T` itself will stay unchanged.  So even if you can narrow `journalState`, it will have no effect on `T` and thus no effect on `journal`.  There are various open issues in GitHub asking for some improvement to this situation, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), but for now nothing is implemented.
- Even if the function weren't generic, the type of `journalState` would be something like `JournalState<SportJournal> | JournalState<ArtJournal>`, which is *not* considered a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions). The `journal.type` subproperty could be seen as a discriminant, but TypeScript only supports discriminant properties at the top level of the object; it does not descend into subproperties to discriminate the union.  There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) asking to support such *nested* discriminated unions, but again, nothing is implemented.

You could try to work around these, but you'll end up with something ugly.

---

Instead, I'd recommend making the function *more* generic and replace control flow branching (`if`/`else`) with a single generic lookup that the compiler can see as valid.  This will require some special refactoring, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The idea is to start with a basic key-value type like:

```
interface JournalMap {
    S: { sport: boolean, id: string },
    A: { art: boolean, id: string }
}
```

and represent your intended operations in terms of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type and generic [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into these mapped types.

So we can define `Journal` like this:

```
type Journal<K extends keyof JournalMap = keyof JournalMap> =
    { [P in K]: { type: P } & JournalMap[P] }[K]
```

.  That's a *distributive object type*, so `Journal` by itself is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) as before, but `Journal<"S">` and `Journal<"A">` are the individual members of that union.  You can  give aliases to these individual pieces if you want:

```
type SportJournal = Journal<"S">;
type ArtJournal = Journal<"A">;
```

We can define `JournalState` similarly to before:

```
type JournalState<T extends Journal<any>> =
    { state: string, journal: T }
```

Instead of `if`/`else`, we make an object that contains the updater functions, into which we'll index with either `"S"` or `"A"`:

```
const journalUpdaters: {
    [K in keyof JournalMap]: (journal: Partial<Journal<K>>) => void
} = {
    S: journal => console.log(journal, journal.sport),
    A: journal => console.log(journal, journal.art)
}
```

It's important that it be explicitly given that mapped type; this allows the compiler to understand that when `k` is of generic type `K`, `journalUpdaters[k]` is of generic type `(journal: Partial<Journal<K>>) => void`... otherwise it would become an unhelpful union.

And now for the generic function:

```
const updateJournalState = <K extends keyof JournalMap>(
    journalState: JournalState<Journal<K>>, journal: Partial<Journal<K>>) => {
    journalUpdaters[journalState.journal.type](journal); // okay
}
```

That compiles without error.  `journalState.journal.type` is known to be of type `K`, and therefore `journalUpdates[journalState.journal.type]` is known to be of type `(journal: Partial<Journal<K>>) => void`, and since `journal` is of type `Partial<Journal<K>>`, the compiler allows the function call.

---

Let's make sure it works from the caller's side:

```
const journalStateSport: JournalState<SportJournal> = {
    state: "A",
    journal: { type: "S", sport: true, id: "id" },
};

updateJournalState(journalStateSport, { id: "a", sport: false }); // okay
updateJournalState(journalStateSport, { art: false }) // error!

const journalStateArt: JournalState<ArtJournal> = {
    state: "Z",
    journal: { type: "A", art: true, id: "xx" }
};
updateJournalState(journalStateArt, { art: false }); // okay
updateJournalState(journalStateArt, { id: "a", sport: false }); // error!
```

Looks good.  The compiler accepts valid calls and rejects invalid ones.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgFIHsCuURwDYCycADsgN4BQy1yAygFznIDOx6UYjARuunhHBAAaZMAAmjZmCigA5sgC+QqjQCCjMsjgduvfoJHjJ0uYooKKFMAE9iKDNlx4APAGlkEAB6QQY5sgBrCGt0GDQsHHwiUgBeQODQ8McokgA+ZBiVak0AbQAFURBkVwBdDWQbO0YChWQAMiTIwhJ8ksUc0stKlFo2DgcmjManZwAiWlHUgG4rWxRVfoinIYGR0dVJmdm7YfxaMDhIZwAVD28IX39V-GdBa1T0zJomKUOIYxkQWREAKyX8RinCwUBDoEBSZB-ZJ4ACqxDEbygzA0WWQHUK8RCYWuzWIZWQAAooU1qtowMAbji3A8AJQZdIAN3Q4nMQ0ozwYkP+eHpyFB4L4EAAdHh0LIidzftyhax2GAacpnuoudDefzmIKRWKJdCpdChWSaeZLOqwMhMPC3jj9m8hm4zj4-JjEjjoqkCajiU4bZBGNaDkcqa4HnqScg8mSKS4g7TeeyaF78HCEZAkTlE3gfcKM0LuiUdU0aTNgaaVU0s705X7uVnnJXFtDHuRUa9fch1qNFQnueVuoxxp2WH1OBUoJgIIYJO3xKNFMoFFsLSmIP63gXvQGIPWwCJNEZ23BB7KdMh4HhmCgFEXkAB6G-IdABODWChLq01zfrvab7e7rQns8L0UOk7w8KAoHYABCE0wQhDMswWEdVyORCcSbeNqFbd52wALU7T0eyYPt2w2EQyUYaRx0nftPE8WcLAXV9LUgZCIC-TNN0Qv9yNPfAgKvKZb3vR9nyY5dWPYhCOD-fdRkPERjxHQDL2vUDoAgqBIKAA)